# Como fazer template editável em ASP.Net MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

Eu vejo em muitos sistemas, (e-commerce principalmente) a possibilidade de editar o template do sistema alterando o CSS e documentos HTML.

Existe alguma engine ou algo parecido em Asp.net MVC?

Esses códigos (CSS,HTML) por serem editáveis são gravados em banco, como é feita a leitura dinamicamente desses códigos?

Comment: Nunca ouvi falar disso, mas não seria má ideia desenvolver algo assim.

Comment: Eu vejo em alguns sistemas de ecommerce, como citei

Comment: Mas deve ser código proprietário. Eu até imagino como fazer, mas não vejo como solução simples, e duvido que algum sistema de e-commerce abriria isso para o Open Source.

Answer (score 1):

O principio de "template" e simplismente um principio de "search replace".
Por exemplo, vc faz um documento HTML com:

```
    <b>Ola senhor XX_NOME_XX, tudo bem?</b>
    Aqui na cidade de XX_CIDADE_XX, tudo certo
```

Neste documento vc coloca palavras chaves, que nao podem ser misturado com outras.
depois precise simplistemnte prepara duas tabelas:

```
$tab_out[0] = "Marcello";
$tab_out[1] = "Brasilia";

$tab_in[0] = "XX_NOME_XX";
$tab_in[1] = "XX_CIDADE_XX";
```

Depois, vc faz um "search replace". Em ASP, nao sei como, mas deve ter um funçao como str_replace() em PHP.

Com um sistema de template um pouco mas avancado, vc pode imaginer TAG para repetir blocos de codigo:
XX_START1_XX et XX_END1_XX por exemplo. O seu codigo vai buscar o incio, buscar o ultimo e copiar muitas vezes o conteudo entre os dois isso por exemplo para mostrar varios produtos.